# What is this exhaust type thing?

Tags: exhaust

What is this black exhaust type thing coming off the side of this land cruiser? 
What is it for?

[image: exhaust]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a fresh air snorkel. The purpose is to raise the air intake so water won't be sucked into the engine while crossing streams or deep puddles.

For a real off roader, the exhaust will also be vented high so there is no water ingress into the engine.

Comment: Also used in the desert to reduce the amount of dust drawn into the filter.